# Excel log scale showing 10^x

Tags: excel, charts

I know that the y-axis in Excel charts can be scaled logarithmically, but the problem is that it displays the axis ticks as normal numbers.

For example, instead of displaying the y-axis ticks as 10<sup>0</sup>, 10<sup>1</sup>, 10<sup>2</sup>, ... etc, Excel uses 1, 10, 100, ... etc. The chart becomes ugly for large y values. I'm also aware that I can use the scientific notation, but they don't look good too.

Is the power notation (10<sup>n</sup>) possible for the y-axis on Excel charts?

I have a Macbook with Excel 2011.

Comment: Downvoter: Can you at least explain why, please? If you convince me that my question is irrelevant, I promise I will delete it.

Comment: I think it is evident that you did not even try to search this anywhere...

Comment: @Aly Abdelaziz : It is evident -from your answer- that you might not have understood my question. I'm not looking for scientific number format (e.g., 1.0E+05), but rather an exponential format (e.g., 10<sup>5</sup>. If I'm wrong, I appreciate answering my comment below your answer.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/742550/superscripts-in-excel-chart-labels

Answer (score -1):

If you right click on the axis, there appear a list of options.
Look for "Numbers" then set the numbering format you wish.

A comprehensive list on the formatting codes are available on the MS Office website.

[Number Format Codes](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Number-format-codes-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: I could not find the format I'm looking for in the URL you provided. Would you please complete your answer with the format I'm looking for?

Comment: You need to use VB for that, and/or a text box. Excel does not support it. or use the notation 10^2.

Comment: Next time, please research your question before you post and make sure you put an effort in explaining it :). Good Luck with your graphing.